# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

working on ionic3, angularfire2 v5

> ```
> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>     at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:73935:76)
>     at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:61778:27)
>     at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
>     at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:26)
>     at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
>     at Subject.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23237:25)
>     at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:26)
>     at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
>     at Notification.observe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51866:50)
>     at AsyncAction.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:76246:40)
> ```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Item } from "../../models/item/item.model";
import {ShoppingListServices} from "../../services/shopping-list/shopping-list.services";



@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  shoppingList$: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  private shopping: ShoppingListServices) {
    this.shoppingList$=this.shopping
      .getShoppingList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(
        changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({
            key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
          }));
        }
      );
  }

}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Shoping List
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button navPush="AddShoppingItemPage" ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Items
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingList$ | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hey, same problem here. I found out, that the error comes from using Firestore within your application. I know this isn't an answer to the problem, but maybe it helps for further investigation.

Comment: yes i am investing. if i found any solution i will post here. you do same

Comment: any success? I am in the same situation right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using AngularFirestore and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works for me, using `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11"`

```
npm i rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 promise-polyfill --save
```

To retrieve the data:

```
this.db.list('/customers').valueChanges().subscribe((datas) => { 
  console.log("datas", datas)
},(err)=>{
   console.log("probleme : ", err)
});
```

Or you can check the GitHub repository for angularfire2  [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1748) for more details

Comment: sir i have got same error and i am not using angularFire ,so it is possible to installed this plugin?

Comment: Ah! Worked for me I was only missing "promise-polyfill" thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Recent releases of AngularFire require rxjs 6. Please upgrade rxjs, you'll need to include `rxjs-compat` if you have dependencies that haven't yet upgraded.

Comment: Angularfire2 version 5.0.0rc 4 solved my problem. But when rc8 or 9 and rxj(changed rxjs_compat). Something else error is coming, error with map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387987/updateing-snapshotchanges-code-to-use-angularfire2-5-0-0-rc-8-firebase-5-0/50401628#50401628

Answer (score 3):

Even though you can run rxjs-compat, its only a matter of time before you need to change your code to reflect the new RXJS. If you are using Angular 6 and the Angular 6 CLI, then you will have RXJS 6, since Angular depends on RXJS for most things. Also if you plan on using Angular Material 2, then you will need Angular 6. So lets just update your RXJS. This will be really important as of Ionic 4. Ionic 4 will depend highly on angular as it will now include the Angular Routes.

Some of the most common changes of RXJS 6 is:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// or 
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Becomes

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

and

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

becomes

import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

and

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

becomes

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: It's worth editing to mention the new pipe() usage for operators.  The link you provided does explain that but I think your answer warrants mentioning it too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install this: Run below command line in CLI

```
npm i rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 promise-polyfill --save
```

Then import these libs to your **home.ts**:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: This suggestion also works for me. In addition to that, I have also downgraded angularfire2 from 5.1.3 to 5.0.0-rc.11

Answer (score 0):

Though my issue isn't related to `angularfire` but searching for 
`TypeError: Object(…) is not a function` brings users to this question.
My issue was that I was using `Youtube Video Player` plugin in ionic v3. But as ionic v3 docs are now auto redirected to ionic v4 docs I was using the latest version of the plugin.

just install version 4 of `Youtube Video Player` plugin and you are good to go.

`npm install --save @ionic-native/youtube-video-player@4`

[Ionic v3 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/youtube-video-player/)

P.S: when you are auto redirected to v4 docs of ionic just insert v3 in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting after installing any new plugin in ionic 3

then just check the version of statusbar or splashscreen plugin in package.json file

```
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
```

and change the version of your installed plugin to same and do

```
npm update
```

it will look like this

```
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
```

Hope it helps someone ...... worked for me for android permission and camera plugin

also, you will need to remove ngx from import statement

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happend to me,
Maybe you are using in your project ionic 3 , and you installing plugins of ionic version 4,
if you are using ionic 3 ,try to install your plugins from  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `rxjs-etc` library and I was getting conflicts for some reason that not only caused the error `TypeError: Object(…) is not a function` but also absolutely killed my CPU in Chrome.

I'm not exactly sure why - it's related to a recent rxjs version being incompatible as far as I can tell - but if you're using this library it can be a cause of this.

Answer (score -1):

I changed from :

```
"angularfire2" : "5.0.0-rc.8.0" and   "firebase": "^5.0.2",
```

to :

```
"angularfire2" : "5.0.0-rc.6.0" and "firebase": "4.12.1"
```

Comment: lets see, i will degrade the version

Comment: Same issue with 6.0.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me:Run below command line in CLI

```
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6 firebase@4.13.1
```

and

```
npm install @firebase/app@^0.1.6
```

Answer (score -4):

I Have a solution :

Simply you can uninstall two package i.e  angularfire2 and firebase

[typeError: Object(...) is not a function ionic](https://youtu.be/0w4XYAly3dE)