# TypeError: this.db.list(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, chat, typeerror

I develop an Ionic 3.9 chat with Firebase and I have the following error:

> TypeError: this.db.list(...).subscribe is not a function

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-consersation',
    templateUrl: 'conversation.html',
})
export class ConversationPage {
    username: string = '';
    message: string = '';
    _chatSubscription;
    s;
    messages;

    constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase,
        public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
          this.username = this.navParams.get('username');
          this._chatSubscription = this.db.list('/conversation').subscribe( data => {
            this.messages = data;
          });
        }

    sendMessage() {
        this.db.list<any>('/conversation').push({
            username: 'romain',
            message: this.message
        }).then( () => {
            // message is sent
        });
        this.message = '';
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `this.db.list('/conversation').subscribe(` you are missing something between the `.list(...)` and the `.subscribe(...`

What you're missing is either `.valueChanges()` or `.snapshotChanges()`... You can read about the differences at [the AngularFire2 documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md).

I typically use .valueChanges() most often, so for a quick example with .valueChanges() your code would be:

```
this._chatSubscription = this.db.list('/conversation').valueChanges().subscribe( data => {
    this.messages = data;
);
```

**EDIT** - corrected code below. Not supposed to set a variable equal to the whole `.subscribe`... Define your pointer/listener, and then subscribe to it separately.

```
this._chatSubscription = this.db.list('/conversation').valueChanges()
this._chatSubscription.subscribe( data => {
    this.messages = data;
);
```

**2nd EDIT** - after new error message that OP posted as answer.
That new error looks like it's due to version conflicts - check out [this question with multiple possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348643/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution with .valueChanges() but I have the following error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Would you help me?

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot, I see my mistake, give me a second to update the answer...

Comment: I tried with your modification but I still have the same mistake

Comment: Does it give you a line number or any other details in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting the following error `polyfills.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function...`, try the following code below:

```
this._chatSubscription = this.db.object('/conversation').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
  this.messages = data;
});
```